# write EPIPE fatal error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodejs, and I followed the guide on the source:-
https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf

I keep getting `Fatal error: write EPIPE` whenever I run grunt. Any idea why?

```
var file_output = 'output.pdf';

    console.log("Warming up");

              var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

              console.log("wkhtmltopdf started");

              wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Hello!</h1>',{ pageSize: 'letter' }, function (err, stream) {    


                if (err) {
                  console.log('wkhtmltopdf error : ', err);
                } else {
                  console.log("Converting!!");

                  var createstream = stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_output));

                  console.log('Done!');

    });
```

Comment: its grunt error try pasting your grunt file here. nithing wrong with code

Comment: I am having same problem

Comment: any solution for this error?